# Can't BIND to Active Directory over LDAPS

Tags: active-directory, ssl, ldap, active-directory-adcs

I have a DC running on Windows Server 2019, and it has the Domain Services role installed. I have a multi-tier CA set up in the same domain using the AD CS role (Root powered off, intermediate powered off, issuing powered on and domain-joined).

I'm having trouble getting third-party clients (i.e. non domain-joined machines and/or web applications) to BIND via LDAPS/636. They work perfectly fine over LDAP/389, and some work with StartTLS, although that's not always an option, and my preference is to use proper LDAPS.

I've generated a certificate for the AD server and made sure to use its FQDN in the Subject of the certificate, as well as including its DNS hostname and IP address as SANs to cover all bases. I've also made sure "Server Authentication" has been selected in the Enhanced Key Usage extension.

I'm yet to verify this as I don't have remote access to the environment, but let's assume the certificate was generated using the Schannel CSP per Microsoft's documentation. The certificate is signed by the correct issuing CA, and the clients have the whole CA chain installed and can verify the AD cert locally (if I export the cert from AD and copy it to one of the clients)

Here's where it gets weird: if I hop on the AD server, open up `ldp.exe`, I can connect via LDAPS/636 using SSL, and `Host supports SSL, SSL cipher strength = 256 bits` appears in the output/console view. However, if I hop on one of the clients -- say, a Linux machine -- and try to connect using openssl:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -state -connect <AD_FQDN>:636
```

I don't get a certificate; I get this instead (I had to write this down instead of copy/paste due to the nature of the network, so there could be slight inaccuracies):

```
CONNECTED (00000003)
write: errno = 104
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client cert CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 324 bytes
Verification: OK
---
<snip>
```

Indeed, if I try to set up a client to use LDAPS for authentication, I'm yet to be able to get it to work. Usually I see something along the lines of this unhelpful error: `SSL_Certificate error: Connection closed by peer` which from my experience usually indicates a certificate verification/trust issue (which would make sense if the client isn't even getting a certificate to verify). Some other clients are even less helpful and just say "Failed to BIND to LDAP server"

The DC is definitely listening on port 636 and I can connect to it externally from the clients (i.e. not just on loopback within the DC machine) which I've verified using netcat

```
nc -vz <AD_FQDN> 636
```

Any ideas of what could be causing this issue?

Comment: Check out my answer here https://serverfault.com/a/1141651/557926

Comment: What does the packet capture on the client show? Does it attempt to access the CRL? Another thing is get an nmap verbose output of SSL/cert script checks.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out our firewall was performing application inspection and breaking the SSL connection. Turning off application inspection resolved my problems.